# Can i execute windows 8 Metro style apps in Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, windows, html, microsoft-metro

I've been browsing for more than 2 hours on the above question, and still couldn't find a clear cut answer. Before i install windows 8 preview edition, i would like to know whether the metro apps (written in JS and HTML5) work in windows 7 as well? If NOT : How does MetroTwit Works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Windows 8 (ex Metro) application requires API that it's not present in Windows 7. Anyway, when you build it from Visual Studio 2012 running in Windows 7, you can run it into an emulator to debug your application even without Windows 8 installed.

Comment: It uses WPF to create the look&feel, not WinRT. Authors created manually the look&feel.